# Mule Runtime Error:Wrong index checksum

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, anypoint-studio

When I am trying to run my Mule application, I get the below error all of a sudden. I tried to restart the Anypoint Studio but that did not help also.

`A Fatal error has occurred while the server was running: java.io.IOException: Wrong index checksum, store was not closed properly and could be corrupted.`

Comment: Can you give us examples of the code you're running? Even the full stack trace would give us more to go by. Currently this question is very vague, "IOException" is one of the most basic exceptions that can apply to a lot of problems.

Comment: What were you doing *before* this error occurred? Did you change any of the code?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this once or twice myself when running applications inside Studio, and the solution for me was to delete the persistent store data related to the project - you should find this in `<studio-workspace-folder>/.mule/.mule/<project-name>`. Next time you start the project the data will be recreated and hopefully all is good.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this error in running the studio when there was multiple java process associated with the anypointstudio. Please check the task manager process tab (if os is Windows) to see if it has multiple and kill the duplicate java process of the studio.

Answer (score 0):

Search for task manager on your system.
In the background processes, click the Java SE process and click end task.
You can then go into your workspace folder and click to open .mule, you will see another .mule folder, click to open it too.
Then delete the folder that has your project name in the second .mule folder that you opened. 
Reopen Anypoint Studio and start your project.
Reference -- This happened to me and that is how I resolved it.